# Creating a set of couples made of two rows in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

From the results of the SQL Server stored procedure 'sp_help' we get a DataSet containing a couple of tables. Seven if i am correct. One of them contains information about the constraints. Each foreign keys is documented by two consecutive rows in that table. The first row contains the constraint type, it's name and other details. It's followed by an empty row except for one column, 'constaint_keys' that contains the column names references of the constraint.

Other constraint types are described in one single row.

Any idea on how to "flatten" this information, using Linq, in a way that we can be sure that any couple made of two rows is really made of rows {n, n + 1}

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Essentially what you want to do is partition an IEnumerable of rows to pairs, right? 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 -> (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8)

Comment: But more precisely, i would like to create pairs only for the foreign keys records because the information is spread on two rows. Other constraint types are described in one single record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[Enumerable.Range()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx)** to get the range of indexes you want to work with:

```
var unflattenedConstraints = constraintsTable.Rows;
var constraints = from index in Enumerable.Range(0, unflattenedConstraints.Count / 2)
                                          .Select(x => x * 2)
                  let row1 = unflattenedConstraints[index]
                  let row2 = unflattenedConstraints[index + 1]
                  // Combine the rows
```

Comment: This is good to retrieve the foreign keys details. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To gather elements of an IEnumerable by two :

`data.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x }).GroupBy(x => x.Index / 2)`

Comment: Sorry for lack of precision in my question: i don't have access to .Net 4.5.

Comment: You dont need .Net 4.5. 3.5 will suffice (maybe even 3.0).

Comment: True. I was referring however to the Zip function that is not available in .Net 3.5, mentioned in the earlier version of your answer. Thanks for your help!